# Download File from http handler with custom name

Tags: jquery, httphandler, xls

I have different files in upload folder with .doc, .docx, .pdf, .xls etc and i want to download file when click on image. I am calling http generic handler from jquery values are pass correctly but not working

```
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileInfo.Name);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", fileInfo.Length.ToString());
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
                HttpContext.Current.Response.TransmitFile(fileInfo.FullName);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileInfo.Name);
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileInfo.Length.ToString());
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.WriteFile(fileInfo.FullName);
Response.End();
```

It should work!